# Number of types in a Typescript 'type'

Tags: typescript, types

If I have the following typescript **type** declared for example:

```
type status = "Running" | "Error" | "Paused" | "Disabled" | "Idle";
```

Is it possible to know the number of types declared here at **runtime** (5 in above example)? 
A similar concept to Object.keys(some_object).length ?

Comment: "*at **runtime***" there are no types at runtime. You can *derive* a type from an array, so you can then examine the array at runtime but the type system only exists at compile time.

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECmEYF4YG0BEASkmGAJZgDmeANDHgKIBOjIjNdACvCqgCbt4AIqQjwARgBs+AgJK8peALox4GUJCgBuAFBQAngAdUcKIhRYY+oyABmJs2gg4wSALZjUjRZqA) for VLAZ's suggestion